# Generate the SAS key for the Azure IoT Central using PowerShell

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-central

I tried the below code to generate the SAS key for the Azure IoT Central.

`az iot central device compute-device-key --pk {primaryKey} --device-id {deviceid}`

But it gives the below error.

[image]

Please let me know how to generate the SAS key for the Azure IoT Central using PowerShell

Comment: [Device authentication concepts in IoT Central](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-device-authentication#automatically-register-devices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your azure-iot extension for Azure CLI. You might also need to update Azure CLI itself.

`az extension update --name azure-iot`

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension#installation